# Sometimes setTimeout is executing multiple times in useEffect

Tags: reactjs, settimeout, use-effect

Here is my setTimeout code in useEffect, where I need to dispatch an action every 28 minutes. For delay, I am using a dynamic value of taking the difference between the current time and a time from the actual API. So that every time it renders it runs at the specified time.

```
const isLogged = useSelector((state) => state.userReducer.loggedIn); // provide boolean value
const intervalId = useRef(null);
const nextRefreshCallValue = localStorage.getItem("nextCall")

useEffect(() => {
  timeoutId.current = setTimeout(() => {
    // To check in between if user is logged out and to stop setTimeout
    if (!isLogged) {
      clearTimeout(timeoutId.current);
      return;
    }
    dispatch(refreshUserToken());
  }, 1000 * moment(currentTime).diff(moment(nextRefreshCallValue))); //it will give diff in milliseconds

  return () => {
    clearTimeout(timeoutId.current)
  }
}, [nextRefreshCallValue, isLogged])
```

It is running as expected, but sometimes when I run the application in multiple browser tabs I can see the timeout is getting executed various times before the next token call (28 minutes), Here I am not using setInterval because we can keep dynamic value every time on new renders in each browser tab.

**My final requirement is** -
All tabs should get the API call at the same time, and it should call after 28 minutes repeatedly.

Can someone please guide me on what mistake I am making here, and how to avoid those situations?

Comment: First of all, I think the timeout id used if the user is logged out uses a closure with the previous timeout id, not the current one. Also, since you're using local storage, multiple tabs running the same site will interfere in terms of the `nextRefreshCallValue`, can't you store that variable in a a state instead?

Comment: @fast-reflexes, I am storing them in local storage because I am also using a storage event listener so that with the help of that listener I can update the all the tabs with a new token, here I need to call the refresh token API at the same time in all the tabs opened, that's why stored in local storage, is there anything that I need to refactor the code, please guide me.